# Spring 4 - Resources mapping - Did not find handler method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I know that there are many topics with this problem because I've gone over all of them. But still I haven't  found any solution.

Basically I have a ResourceHandler that maps a resource but doesn't find the css file while entering the jsp. I'm using Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE.

**The project look like this**

[image: File hierarchy]

**Web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        com.res.context.MvcConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Configuration file looks like this:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.res"})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
//I've already tried without this
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    super.configurePathMatch(configurer);
    configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    configurer.enable();
}
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
}
```

**The jsp file**

I've already tried many values of href

```
//Those two give 404 error code
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css" type="text/css">
//Those two give jsp fatal error with NullPointerException
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:uri>value="/resources/style.css"</c:uri> 'type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:uri>value="resources/style.css"</c:uri> 'type="text/css">
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

public class MyController {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class);
@RequestMapping("/site")
public ModelAndView site()
{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("site");
    model.addObject("txt", "Model");
    return model;

}}
```

And finally most important part

**logs**

```
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:869 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/res/site.htm]
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /site.htm
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Did not find handler method for [/site.htm]
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /site.htm
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:317 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.res.controller.MyController.site()]
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myController'
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:955 - Last-Modified value for [/res/site.htm] is: -1
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:1670 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'site'
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1280 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'site'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/site.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG JstlView:432 - Added model object 'txt' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'site'
2017-07-18 20:56:35 DEBUG JstlView:166 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/site.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'site'
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:869 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/res/resources/style.css]
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/style.css
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/style.css]
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/style.css
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:320 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/style.css]
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:192 - Matching patterns for request [/resources/style.css] are [/resources/**]
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:226 - URI Template variables for request [/resources/style.css] are {}
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:140 - Mapping [/resources/style.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4c531172]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:955 - Last-Modified value for [/res/resources/style.css] is: -1
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1048 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-07-18 20:56:36 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

I hope that someone knows what is wrong here because after few hours I can't think of anything more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294406/spring-static-resource-mapping?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have the folder resources out of `webapp` and your servlet is looking at `webapp` as `/`.

**First way**:

Move your **resources** folder under `webapp` and then into your **applicationContext.xml** add the next line:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/" />
```

then you can import your style.css file like this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Second way**:

you can create another **Servlet** for static content:

First add the next few lines in your **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.res.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
```

next step, create the package `com.res.servlet` the under that package create the class **DefaultServlet** like this:

```
public class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet
{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, and GlassFish 
    private static final String COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "default";

    // Resin 
    private static final String RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "resin-file";

    // WebLogic 
    private static final String WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "FileServlet";

    // WebSphere 
    private static final String WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME = "SimpleFileServlet";


    public String scanDefaultServlet(){
        if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
            return COMMON_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null) {
            return RESIN_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
            return WEBLOGIC_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else if(this.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME) != null){
            return WEBSPHERE_DEFAULT_SERVLET_NAME;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot determine what Server you currently use");
        }       
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(this.scanDefaultServlet());
        HttpServletRequest wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
                public String getServletPath() {return "";}
        };
        rd.forward(wrapped, resp);
    }
}
```

now you can call your resources like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/resources/style.css"/>">
```

Make sure you has imported the tag libs like this at the top of your view:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've  saved my day!